# How to set up test container with datastax enterprise cassandra?

Tags: java, docker, datastax

I can set up test containers with a regular version of cassandra, but trying to use a DSE version throws this error

`org.testcontainers.shaded.org.awaitility.core.ConditionTimeoutException: org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer expected the predicate to return <true> but it returned <false> for input of <InspectContainerResponse(`

This is my current set up that is failing

```
@TestConfiguration
class TestContainer {
  private static final String ROC_KEYSPACE = "cksdgmdp1";
  private static CassandraContainer cassandraRocContainer;
  private static final String DSE_IMAGE_VERSION =
          "artifactory.aexp.com/dockerproxy/datastax/dse-server:5.1.10";
  @BeforeAll
  static void setupCassandraConnectionProperties() {
    System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "e0");
    System.setProperty("spring.profiles.env", "e0");
  }

  @Bean("cassandraRocSession")
  public CassandraSession getCassandraRocSession() {
    DockerImageName myImage =
        DockerImageName.parse(DSE_IMAGE_VERSION)
            .asCompatibleSubstituteFor("cassandra");

    cassandraRocContainer =
        (CassandraContainer)
            new CassandraContainer(myImage)
                .withInitScript(getCqlScript(ROC_KEYSPACE))
                .withExposedPorts(9042);
    // start container
    cassandraRocContainer.start();
    // create cluster object from container
    Cluster cluster =
        Cluster.builder()
            .addContactPoint(cassandraRocContainer.getHost())
            .withPort(cassandraRocContainer.getMappedPort(9042))
            .withCredentials("", "")
            .build();

    // create session from newly created keyspace
    Session session = cluster.connect(ROC_KEYSPACE);
    return new CassandraSession(session, ROC_KEYSPACE);
  }

  public String getCqlScript(String keyspace) {
    return String.format("%s.cql", keyspace);
  }

  @AfterAll
  static void shutdown() {
    cassandraRocContainer.close();
  }
}
```

If i change that `DSE_IMAGE_VERSION` to `cassandra:3.11.4` then it works fine but I need to use a DSE version. I'm not sure what to try to be honest, I am pretty new with both DSE and containers.

Comment: You need to get the logs from the container which failed to start, and see what the problem is. Does that version work if you start it yourself, in docker?

Comment: I believe you need to add `.withEnv("DS_LICENSE", "accept")` to container build chain

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov That worked! How did you know? I didn't see any documentation for this anywhere ;(

Comment: that is mentioned in https://hub.docker.com/r/datastax/dse-server. `DS_LICENSE`: **Required**. Set to accept to acknowledge that you agree with the terms of the DataStax license. To show the license, set the variable `DS_LICENSE` to the value `accept`. **The image only starts if the variable set to accept**.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/datastax/dse-server), `DS_LICENSE=accept` environment variable has to be presented.

> Examples Create a DSE database container:
> `docker run -e DS_LICENSE=accept --name my-dse -d datastax/dse-server:<version tag>`

Try the following approach:

```
DockerImageName myImage = DockerImageName.parse("artifactory.aexp.com/dockerproxy/datastax/dse-server:5.1.10")
        .asCompatibleSubstituteFor("cassandra");

CassandraContainer cassandraContainer = new CassandraContainer<>(myImage)
        .withEnv("DS_LICENSE", "accept");

cassandraContainer.start();
```